# How to use Memcache and Ruby On Rails default memory store at the same time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I am using memcached (gem `memcache-client`) in my application, but I want to use the memory cache store at the same time. I currently have the following in my `application.rb`:

```
config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store, {:namespace => "my_namespace_#{Rails.env}"}
```

and this works fine with commands such as `Rails.cache.write(...)`

How can I use the `ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore` for some of my models, and at the same time use memcached for other reasons as I do until now?

I know that `ActiveSupport::Cache.lookup_store` will return to me a new `MemoryStore` object. However, I do not know how to continue from this point on? For example, where do I put this command? Where do I store the resulting object? How do I access this object later on from inside my model code? Or shall I follow a completely different way?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: not really answering your question but just curious as to why you need both stores in your app?

Comment: I think I might get better performance for some models I want immediate access. Instead of having to do interprocess communication (when memcached is on same server) or intermachine communication (when memcached is on different server) I will be accessing my objects from the in-process memory.

Comment: I get that, however, that'd be relying on the fact you only have one process running. If you have several processes, the memory store won't be shared, so if your user hits a process that hasn't loaded the object into memory yet, it'll hit the DB again, 1 time per process. That doesn't really scale and overall you're better off using memcached.  unless you're running a single process app and that's not going to change anytime soon.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and comment. I voted your comment up. Will consider it thoroughly accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Rails.cache` is just a cache store that is created for your convenience. There's nothing stopping you doing something like

```
::MEMORY_STORE = ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore.new
```

and then when you want to use that store instead of `Rails.cache` you would do

```
MEMORY_STORE.fetch('some_key') {}
```

Although, as @leonardoborges commented, I'm not sure why you would want to do this

Comment: This answer is almost correct. I have sent you a small edit / correction to make it work correctly. Waiting for you to make the correction so that I can accept this answer.

Comment: Yes. That was my correction. (I do not know how the edit notification work with SOW).